# Need Help to rerun a python code after every 5 min

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, computer-vision, python-sockets

Hey Guys I want a code which can rerun a python code after every 5 min.

I am communicating with 2 cameras(smart camera) via socket programming. The socket is created and communication is working good but after every 15 min any one o the camera refuse to connect then we have to rerun the program after every 15 min.

I want help to rerun the code automatically after every 5 min. Is it possible in python or any other language will be preferable but python is priority. Only thing to be noted that our main program is written in python and it is written in pycharm ide on a windows system

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a code for it. There are tools available for that.

1. For Linux, you can use CRON jobs.
2. For Windows, you can use Task Scheduler.
3. You can use Jenkins too.

Just create a bash/cmd script run.cmd/run.sh like

```
python app.py
```

and then point this script to the jobs, set the interval to 5 minutes and the OS will automatically run it in every 5 minutes.